# Can not call the method from interface

Tags: java

Hi guys i have a program that is library management program

I have a method called borrowHolding(holdingId)throws BalanceLow, InvalidHolding
i am calling that from model interface which calls facade class which pass method call to library class but from here the method definition is declared in interface borrower, Another interface Member extends this borrower interface and then the AbstractMember implements the borrowHoling method may small coding snippets clear:

All import are correct and each class and interface are separated in different calss.

```
  public interface LMSModel {
    public void borrowHolding(int holdingId)
                throws InsufficientCreditException, MultipleBorrowingException;
    }


    public class LMSFacade implements LMSModel {
    private Library lib = new Library();
        private Member member;
    public void borrowHolding(int holdingId)
                throws InsufficientCreditException, MultipleBorrowingException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            lib.borrowHolding(holdingId);

        }
    }


    public class Library {
    public Member member;
    public void borrowHolding(int holdingId) throws InsufficientCreditException, MultipleBorrowingException {

            member.borrowHolding(holdingId);
        }
    }


        public interface Member extends Borrower{
    public abstract Holding[] getCurrentHoldings(); 
        public abstract double getMaxCredit();  
        public abstract void resetCredit();
        public abstract String getFullName();
        public abstract String getMemberId();

    }


    public abstract class AbstractMember implements Member, Borrower {
        public void borrowHolding(int holdingId)
                    throws InsufficientCreditException, MultipleBorrowingException {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("Hello");
    //      Map<Integer, Holding> LibHoldingMap = libCollection.holdingMap;     
    //      holding = (Holding)LibHoldingMap.get((Integer)holdingId);
    //      
    //      if (holding.isOnLoan()) {
    //          System.out.println("Can not be issued Currently on Load");
    //      } else {
    //          System.out.println("Can be issued");
    //      }
        }
    }

    public interface Borrower {
        void borrowHolding(int holdingId)throws InsufficientCreditException, MultipleBorrowingException; 
    }
```

when i am calling the borrowHolding i am getting nullPointerException i don't know the method can not be called don't know why.

Comment: Is member initialized in Library class?

Comment: `member` is never initialized in your `Library` class...

Answer (score 0):

`member` attribute is never initialized in your `Library` class, so you will get a `NullPointerException` every time you try to use it.

Since `member` is an instance of interface `Member` you can't construct it directly. For this, you should provide a class that implements the `Member` interface. I post two example of how you can solve this problem:

1. Using a class that implements the interface:

   ```
   public class MemberImpl implements Member {
       public void borrowHolding(int holdingId)
           throws InsufficientCreditException, MultipleBorrowingException {
           //some code here...
       }
   }

   public class Library {
       public Member member = new MemberImpl();
       //...
   }
   ```
2. Instantiating an anonymous class that implements the interface:

   ```
   public class Library {
       public Member member = new Member() {
           public void borrowHolding(int holdingId)
               throws InsufficientCreditException, MultipleBorrowingException {
               //some code here...
           }
       };
       //...
   }
   ```

A̶l̶t̶e̶r̶n̶a̶t̶i̶v̶e̶l̶y̶,̶ ̶s̶i̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶i̶m̶p̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶`̶b̶o̶r̶r̶o̶w̶H̶o̶l̶d̶i̶n̶g̶`̶ ̶m̶e̶t̶h̶o̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶i̶d̶e̶ ̶`̶M̶e̶m̶b̶e̶r̶`̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶f̶a̶c̶e̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶m̶e̶a̶n̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶d̶e̶c̶l̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶t̶e̶a̶d̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶f̶a̶c̶e̶

```
public class Member implements Borrower {
    //...
}
```

O̶t̶h̶e̶r̶w̶i̶s̶e̶,̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶`̶M̶e̶m̶b̶e̶r̶`̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶d̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶f̶a̶c̶e̶,̶ ̶r̶e̶m̶e̶m̶b̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶f̶a̶c̶e̶s̶ ̶*̶*̶d̶o̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶i̶m̶p̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶ ̶m̶e̶t̶h̶o̶d̶*̶*̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶y̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶i̶n̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶a̶c̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶i̶m̶p̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶ ̶m̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶f̶o̶l̶l̶o̶w̶.̶

EDIT:

Similar to interfaces, abstract classes **cannot be instantiated directly**, you will need a class that extends the abstract class. The solution would be similar to provided solution:

1. Using a class that directly extends the abstract `AbstractMember` class:

   ```
   public ConcretMember extends AbstractMember {
   }

   public class Library {
       public Member member = new ConcretMember();
       //...
   }
   ```
2. Instantiating an anonymous class that extends the abstract `AbstractMember` class:

   ```
   public class Library {
       public Member member = new AbstractMember() {
           @Override
           public void borrowHolding(int holdingId)
               throws InsufficientCreditException, MultipleBorrowingException {
               //some code here...
           }
       };
       //...
   }
   ```

Comment: but how to initialize that bec member is interface and implementation is done inside the AbstractMember class

Comment: @monty answer updated. By the way, is the same problem just with different design.

Comment: what exactly happening is that if i am calling that method that i have implemented in AbstractMember class but that class is further extended by two other classes Say StandardMember and PremiumMember so how to initialize the Member interface

Comment: But you see i want to make it generic method means if i initialize it with anyone of them then it will work only with the objects of that particular class. so shall i instantiate it with AbstractMember class and there are 3 different constructor for them so does that affect the behaviour of the program.

Comment: @monty Use a [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)...